# 2.8 textures are messed up when rendered but fine in look dev

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine

when I try to render this scene in cycles I end up with the textures not coming out properly:
[image: Cycles]

It also has errors in Eevee but not as severe:[image: Eevee]

But it looks perfrctly normal when I do a viewport render in Look Dev[image: Look Dev]

I have tried this in two different versions of 2.8 including the most recent version and one from the start of the year

the same problem has happend to me on most of my projects in 2.8

I assume that this is a bug but any help would be apreciated :)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can use overlapping UV islands if you're using a normal map. Maybe try using a geometry node using Object or generated for the normal map? Also, make sure your sub-div modifer (if using one) that the viewpoint and render value is the same.

Comment: May be these object are duplicated and the doubles are hidden only in viewport but not in render.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it. thanks so much for telling me that, it has just saved me a lot of wasted time!